# Existe uma forma correta de escrever esse código?

Tags: java

```
package linguagem;
import java.util.*;
public class Linguagem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("PORTUGUESE", "PT");
        System.out.println("Linguagem: " + locale.getDefault());
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o `locale.getDefault()` retornando `en_US`, torna-se desnecessária a utilização de `Locale("PORTUGUESE", "PT")`, porém, se eu deixar apenas `Locale()`, o NetBeans me retorna erro.

E se eu deixar a string vazia: `Locale("", "")`, funciona, mas fica parecendo gambiarra.

Queria saber se existe outra forma de escrever esse código, sem ter que deixar a variável vazia.

Comment: `new Locale("portuguese", "pt")` **não** retorna um locale que corresponde ao idioma português. O problema é que o construtor [não valida a entrada e aceita qualquer coisa](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). O correto para português de Portugal é `new Locale("pt", "PT")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método `getDefault()` [é estático e sempre retornará a Locale default da JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault()).

Acredito que o que você quer na verdade é:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("portuguese", "pt");
System.out.println("Linguagem: " + locale);
```

Ou, pra pegar a `Locale` default:

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
System.out.println("Linguagem: " + locale);
```